# Nagios : Error: Could not stat() command file '/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd'!

Tags: linux, centos, nagios

I have installed Nagios on Centos 6.4.
I am trying to enable notification service of SSH and http service of host. but while i commit it I got below error.

**Error: Could not stat() command file '/usr/local/nagios/var/rw/nagios.cmd'!**

**The external command file may be missing, Nagios may not be running, and/or Nagios may not be checking external commands.**

An error occurred while attempting to commit your command for processing.

Specifiactions are as follows

nagios - 4.0

centos - 6.4

user - nagios

group - nagcmd

Comment: Probably SELinux, you might want to check your logs.

Comment: yaeh but i already disabled it.

Comment: What are the permissions and user/group of /usr/local/nagios/var/rw/? Should be drwxrwsr-x 2 nagios nagcmd

Answer (score 0):

SElinux can throw some strange errors and not allow you to connect with the cgi's on certain stock Distro setups. Run the following commands

```
getenforce
```

if it is enabled run:

```
setenforce 0
```

then

```
service nagios restart
```

This should solve the issue